# Store PHP variable to use in javascript later on in the same script

Tags: javascript, php, unity-game-engine

I know that PHP happens server-side and javascript is executed once the page loads in the browser. I'm trying to figure out how to save a variable in PHP so that it can be used in a javascript function later on. Here are the bits of my code where I'm trying to do that.

This all happens in the same index.php script:

```html
    <? 
    // If session token exists, set javascript variable 
    if($_SESSION['token'] != null) 
    { 
        // Store session token as a variable 
        $sessionToken = $_SESSION['token']; 
    } 
    ?>

    <script>
      // Turn that PHP variable into a javascript variable
      var sessionToken = '<? echo $sessionToken; ?>';
    </script>

    <script>
      // This function works. It sends a string to the Unity web player
      // I'm trying to call it using a PHP variable as a parameter
      function SessionTokenToUnity($token) {
        // Send message to unity web player from browser
        u.getUnity().SendMessage("Settings", "MyFunction", $token);
      }
    </script>

    <script>
      // Call function with sessionToken which was set by PHP earlier as a parameter
      SessionTokenToUnity(sessionToken);
    </script>
```

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['token'])` is better than using `$_SESSION[ 'token'] !=null`. Additionally, `$sessionToken` does not have a default value, you should initialize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `session_start();` at beggining of your file to be able to use `$_SESSION`.

And you have some sintax errors like:

`if($_SESSION[ 'token'] !=n ull)`

`$sessionToken=$ _SESSION[ 'token'];`

it should be

`if($_SESSION['token'] !=null)`

`$sessionToken=$_SESSION['token'];`

Edit: And you should use isset($_SESSION['token']) like ByteHamster told it.

Comment: He is also using `n ull` instead of `null`

Comment: I saw it later and have edit my answer, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Woops. I pasted my code wrong, I fixed it. In my script it was good. Sorry about that, this is my first post on here

Comment: I just solved it! Turns out I was trying to send the Unity web player a function before it had even loaded. Thanks for your reply